# Magento Batch Import Takes Forever On live database but faster on local site

Tags: apache, magento, networking, webserver

We are running a batch import of about 1600 products. When I run our import script on the live server it takes 7-8 hours.

On my local machine it takes 15 minutes. Could there be something wrong with the database that I could fix in order to get the import to run quickly?

**It seems over time this import has gotten longer and longer. I remember when it used to only take 20 minutes on the live server.**

Now $adapter->saveRow($importData); takes 8 minutes for one or two rows.

Any direction as to how to speed this up would be greatly appreciated.

Magento 1.6.2 community edition running on a (unfortunately) cherokee based webserver with 4GB Ram and no other sites on the server. The server has plenty of power.

```
if ($batchModel->getAdapter()) {
    $batchId = $batchModel->getId();
    $batchImportModel = $batchModel->getBatchImportModel();
    $importIds = $batchImportModel->getIdCollection();
    $batchModel = Mage::getModel('dataflow/batch')->load($batchId);
    $adapter = Mage::getModel($batchModel->getAdapter());
    $records = count($importIds);
    progressBar(0, $records, 50);
    foreach ($importIds as $importId) {
        progressBar($recordCount);
        $recordCount++;
        try {
            $batchImportModel->load($importId);
            if (!$batchImportModel->getId()) {
                $errors[] = $importId . " - empty batchImportModel ID";
                continue;
            }
            $importData = $batchImportModel->getBatchData();
            delete_product_image_by_sku($importData['sku']);
            try {
                $adapter->saveRow($importData);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $errors[] = $importId . " - cannot save row with sku: " . $importData['sku'] . " error: " . $e->getMessage();
                continue;
            }
        } catch(Exception $ex) {
            $errors[] = $importId . " - error: " . $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
    progressBar($records);
    echo implode("\n", $errors);
}
```

Comment: are the live shop and your local shop 100% similar? (both DB and files). A possible scenario and reason of the slowness is that it tries to reindex catalog after each saved row.

Comment: I downloaded the live DB and that did not increase the speed on the local machine. I also added the function that is taking the most time. Specifically *$adapter->saveRow($importData);* If that is removed. The script runs really fast. We use a deployment strategy through github. The sites are as alike as they can be.

Comment: hm ... I'd suggest to look into my.cnf (google how to optimize mysql for optimal Magento performance). First thing coming to mind is that there is not enough memory dedicated for SQL operations.

Comment: Yea, I updated the mysql settings to a better level but I am not getting any increase in performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and ended up using Magmi.